# Горячие клавиши Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, hotkeys

Столкнулся с проблемой, что в проекте WPF неудобно работать на пол окна с редактором XAML и пол окна с конструктором. Сделал отображение на весь экран, но теперь, чтобы перейти с конструктора на редактор и обратно, нужно постоянно кликать мышью.

С редактора на конструктор можно перейти <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Кто-нибудь знает горячую клавишу для обратного действия? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> переводят на код, а нужно именно на XAML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shift + F7 Делает то что нужно, т.е. работает как Toggle. Туда и обратно переключает.